# Python replace function is not working(I'm assigning the return value back to the variable)

Tags: python, pandas, regex

So this is my DataFrame before applying replace:
[df before replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWgXr.png)

This is my code:

```
movies_df['year'] = movies_df.title.str.extract('(\(\d\d\d\d\))',expand=False)
movies_df['year'] = movies_df.year.str.extract('(\d\d\d\d)',expand=False)

movies_df['title'] = movies_df['title'].str.replace('(\(\d\d\d\d\))', '')
movies_df['title'] = movies_df['title'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())

movies_df.head()
```

I am using Regular Expression to select the part in the title column that has  parentheses and four digits within it.

As you see I'm assigning the return value of `replace()` to `movies_df['title']`,
but its still not working: [df after replace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcCsP.png)

Comment: `Series.str.replace` has a `regex` parameter that I think you want to set to True. You should probably use a r-string for the regex patterns too.

Comment: yeah you're right, the `regex` parameter worked!
Thank you my friend <3

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to create an own column and remove part of the str:

```
import pandas as pd

col = ['movieID','title','genre']
no = ['1','2','3']
movie = ['M1 (1961)','M2 (1965)','M3 (1978)']
genre = ['comedy |fantasy','comedy','fantacy']

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(no, movie, genre)), columns=col)
print(df, '\n')

df['year'] = df['title'].str.slice(-6, )
df['title']= df['title'].str.replace("\(\d+\)", " ", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  movieID      title            genre
0       1  M1 (1961)  comedy |fantasy
1       2  M2 (1965)           comedy
2       3  M3 (1978)          fantacy 

  movieID title            genre    year
0       1  M1    comedy |fantasy  (1961)
1       2  M2             comedy  (1965)
2       3  M3            fantacy  (1978)
```